# Wubi cannot retrieve the required disk image file

Tags: wubi, downloads, iso

I have already downloaded the ubuntu-12.04-wubi-amd64.tar.xz file...i have no internet connection. When I run wubi, I'm getting this message: `could not retrieve the required disk image file.`
i used other way..i put ubuntu-12.04-wubi-amd64.tar.xz in ubuntu\disk but it not works..

How can I get the install to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into that `temp\wubi` log file, check for an error. I got authentication problems and had to enable my firewall for `wubi.exe` for both inbound and outbound. Check it dude.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too. It was becaus of **a bad Internet connection**. You should check if you're using a bad proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

You might look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wubi

Before you do a wubi install, you ought to burn a DVD and boot from the live DVD.  There is an option 'Try Ubuntu'.  Try that first before doing any installation just in case it is not compatible with your hardware.  When you say 'I've put both the files in same folder' I am not clear what you mean.  The normal way is to burn a DVD and run the autopla from Windows.  Please clarify.